Making a 30A L6-30, 5 port power strip
My wood working shop currently has a single 30A circuit that runs to an L6-30 outlet.  The outlet was installed by the original contractor who built the shop for me.  Currently my table saw is plugged directly into that outlet.  Everything else in the shop runs off standard 110v/20amp outlets.
But, I just bought two new toys for the shop.  A planer and a bandsaw - and I need help understanding what I need to do/change to get the one 30A circuit to feed power to all three machines.
The table saw power requirements:

220v single phase 60 hz
Minimum circuit size: 20A
Plug type: 6-20
Cord: 14 AWG
NOTE: The original cord/plug was replaced with a 12AWG and L6-30
connector

The Planer power requirements:

230-v single phase 60hz
Minimum circuit size: 20A
Plug type: 6-20
Cord: 12AWG

The bandsaw power requirements:

110v OR 220v single phase 60hz
Comes prewired for 220v
Min circuit: 30A at 100V, 15A at 220v
Plug Type: L5-30 for 110V, 6-15 for 220v
Cord: 14 AWG

I will only ever be running/working one tool at a time.  So, what I would like to do (and please suggest a better solution if there is one) is use my existing 30amp L6-30 outlet to connect (with a 2ft pigtail) to a custom made "power strip"...in that power strip would be an L6-30 outlet (for table saw), a 6-20 outlet (for planer) and a 6-15 outlet (for bandsaw).  And then each tool would plug into each corresponding outlet in the power strip - all being fed from the one 30amp L6-30 outlet/circuit.  I will need to run new power cables to both the planer and bandsaw because they are both too far from the 30A outlet to use the power cables they come with - so I could change out the plug types of both to L6-30 (or other) plugs.  I would also like it to be a 5 port power strip for future tools I may buy.
Knowing the specs of everything above....would this power strip concept work?  Are there existing products like this or special boxes I could buy to use house my the 3 to 5 outlets in?
Or is there a better way to do this?   I was looking for 220/230v power strips but the only thing I have ever been able to find were a different types of L6-30 splitters (turning one outlet into two outlets).  The fact that something like this doesn't already exist (beyond two ports) makes me wonder if there is a reason for this.
Thank you.
IDEA UPDATE:
The other thing I could do is to convert my 30A outlet into a junction box that fed lines to various points in my shop, distributing the outlets to where the tools are setup - then just plug my tools into that localized outlet.  The down side of that though is that i have to continue to expand the junction box every time I add a new 230v/30amp tool.  I think I still like the power strip concept...OR...better yet, keep the power strip concept and run lines to each tool station with a new outlet at that station, then plug the tool into that localized outlet.
Thoughts?

Your question may be better suited to the DIY/Home Improvement stack - there are several experts there who are familiar with AC power wiring practices and regulations.

None of your ideas are safe and do not comply with known electrical codes. You must hire an electrician to install a feeder, branch circuit sub-panel, and all the outlets you want. There is a reason you cannot find any power strips to do what you want. A company would quickly go bankrupt from lawsuits. They would be defenseless because no agency like UL or CE would certify for use. It is a fire waiting to happen. So goferit.

Power strips aren't recommended for high power loads like these. Fine for laptops, lights, phone chargers and the likes but not heavy current users.

Keep the one outlet, and just plug in one tool at a time. That is the failsafe solution.

well, none of this is good news, but also explains my hunch as to why I can't find any existing products.  Obviously I don't know enough about electrical..  You can find 240v/30amp power strips but all the ports are for standard 3 prong plugs.  I guess I don't understand why the concept wouldn't work IF I was only running one tool a time, how would that overload or be a fire hazard?  If I were trying to run two tools a time I can see the problem...but if only one tool was pulling power how would that be an issue.

@rolinger It works with the IF you said. At some point, someone will come and turn on two devices, even if accidentally, and burn a fuse. It makes no sense to have a working setup with an IF waiting to happen. Just like you at home expect to plug in anything you want and use them at the same time, without thinking if you can use your laptop while charging a phone, or fuse blowing when someone else starts to charge a phone while your laptop is already charging.

The ideal solution is to have a dedicated receptacle for each machine. However, you can add the additional 2 receptacles onto the existing feed. Install them in a junction box near their respective machine. They will need to be wired with 12AWG minimum (10AWG if it's over 100ft from the service) and fused for 20A.

There are L6-30 to 2x L6-20 splitters out there from reputable sources. I'm sure you could find L6-30 plug to multiple L6-30 socket cordsets out there from wherever but I wouldn't trust them.
You're not finding a lot of variety like you do for "standard" 5-15 outlets because the only reason to use a large, heavy, expensive connector like a L6-30 is because you need the locking plug and a 20A drop wasn't enough. That means there's not going to be a case like with power strips where you have half a dozen devices plugged in and your total draw is 8A. And a "temporary" arrangement where you have to run several 220V 30A loads, but only one at a time is so specialized that it's not worth making a product to fill that niche.
